# Loop through a large list to look for certain values

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a notepad document listing all the zipcodes in America and I want to look for a particular zipcode (specified by the user), run some code on that zipcode that prints out a statement like `"The temperature at [input] is 60"`And I want to do that for the specified zipcode and the next 10 sequential ones that appear in my zipcode dossier. My first issue is that I don't know how to convert this zipcode document containing all these numbers into a list or array or whatever makes it easy to run a for loop on. I'm extremely new to R so bear with me.

```
Input = "20904"# User provides an input for this
    ZipData<-read.csv(file.path(wd,"DataImport","zip_code_data.csv"),
                      colClasses=c("character","NULL","factor","NULL","NULL","factor",
                                   "NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL",
                                   "NULL","NULL"),
                      col.names=c("zip","","city","","","state","","","","","","","","",
                                  "",""))
    ZipData<- as.numeric(ZipData$zip)
edit(ZipData) # Opens up a notepad document listing the zipcodes starting with "c(544, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614....)
# Note: typeof(ZipData) prints out "double"

    # Bunch of code that ends with:
    a <- paste("The current temperature for", cityName, Input, "is", temperature, sep=" ")
    print(a)
```

I want to run this on the Input and the next 10 zipcodes that follow. I am having trouble formulating a for-loop that loops through the entire list (I don't know if ZipData can be classified as a list), finds the user specified zipcode, runs my block of code on it and rinses and repeats for the next 10 zipcodes. My program should end with 10 print statements listing all of their temperatures. Any ideas?

Comment: Not enough information. You mention "current" values, but does your data contain a time dimension and we're reporting the most recent value? And you ask about the next 10 zip codes but fail to define it. Is it the next ten seen in the (sorted) data? Is it a series of inputs from the user? In any case, I suspect the `match` function might help, like `match(Input,ZipData$zip)` will get you the correct row quickly.

Comment: @Frank The zipcodes are all arranged sequentially. So it's just a matter of getting the next 10 elements that appear in the list(?) after the Input zipcode. My issue is trying to find the index of the Input element in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're referring to:

```
zip_plus10 <- function(input) {
  index <- which(zip.vector == as.numeric(input))
  paste('The current temperature for',
        city[index:(index+10)],
        state[index:(index+10)],
        zip.vector[index:(index+10)],
        'is: ',
        temps[index:(index+10)]
        )
}

zip_plus10('90210')

 [1] "The current temperature for K HI 90210 is:  65" 
 [2] "The current temperature for L ID 90211 is:  66" 
 [3] "The current temperature for M IL 90212 is:  58" 
 [4] "The current temperature for N IN 90213 is:  110"
 [5] "The current temperature for O IA 90214 is:  57" 
 [6] "The current temperature for P KS 90215 is:  91" 
 [7] "The current temperature for Q KY 90216 is:  90" 
 [8] "The current temperature for R LA 90217 is:  89" 
 [9] "The current temperature for S ME 90218 is:  108"
[10] "The current temperature for T MD 90219 is:  109"
[11] "The current temperature for U MA 90220 is:  55" 

#Data
    set.seed(444)
zip.vector <- seq(90200, 90221)
city <- LETTERS[1:length(zip.vector)]
state <- state.abb[1:length(zip.vector)]
temps <- sample(50:110, length(zip.vector))
```

Comment: +1 for providing sample data (as the OP arguably should have). I think `match` is better than `==`, since it will stop when it finds the match. Also, to mirror the OP, you might want to add `ZipData <- data.frame(zip.vector,city,state,temps)` and then do your operations inside a `with(ZipData,{})`. Finally, I think `cat` might be nicer than `paste` for showing results to a user.

Comment: @Frank `cat` will work with some manuevering. I like `match` also. Thank you. btw do you get a green jacket when you cross the 1,000 rep threshold : )

Comment: Is that a golf reference? Congrats on passing that threshold :)

Comment: it is. I guess a digital badge will have to do.